# Bash script for fetching row from Postgresql

Tags: linux, bash, postgresql

I have a Postgresql function which returns table of JSON strings.

I want to fetch those rows under the Linux platform and run CURL program for each string like this:

```
curl http://XXX.XX.XX.XX:XXXX/update/json -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d ['||solr_interface.dict_cursor_okpd_json()||']'
```

Do you have any example how to do this using say bash script?

Thanks in advise.

Comment: I don't see how the curl part is relevant, unless you don't even know how to save a string to a parameter and later expand it in bash. Might as well edit that out as it muddles the question.

Comment: Yeah, I see. The main point of the question is how to fetch rows usig bash script. The mention of curl is the point what I want to get as result.

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution. Maybe it will useful for somebody

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# != 2 ]; then
    echo "Please select postgres procedure for data retrieving as first parameter"
    echo "and Solr index name (dictionary or company) as second parameter"
    exit 1;
fi

PSQL=/usr/bin/psql

DB_USER="xxxxxxxx"
DB_PASSWORD="xxxxxxxx"
DB_HOST="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
DB_PORT="xxxx"
DB_NAME="portal_sources"

export PGPASSWORD=$DB_PASSWORD

$PSQL \
    -X \
    -h $DB_HOST \
    -p $DB_PORT $DB_NAME \
    -c "select 'curl http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/solr/$2/update/json -H ''Content-type:application/json'' -d ''['||$1||']'''" \
    --single-transaction \
    --set AUTOCOMMIT=off \
    --set ON_ERROR_STOP=on \
    --no-align \
    -t \
    --field-separator ' ' \
    --quiet \
| while read command ; do
    #echo "$command"
    eval $command
done
```